# Sub or Function not defined System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working with an application that auto-runs excel macros.  When testing I receive this:

> Error running macro RefreshAllPMWS, Component Name : Module1 === Error
> Message : Sub or Function not defined Component Name : Module2 ===
> Error Message : Sub or Function not defined
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException:
> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0009
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers,
> Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters) at
> System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
> bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
> ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
> namedParams)

Here is the code from module 1:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Month_End()


' Month_End Macro
' Updates Formulas for YTD ME to include the most recent day's PnL
'

    Range("D15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+SUM(RC[2]:RC[106])"
    Range("D15").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D15:D88")
    Range("D15:D88").Select
    Range("B12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("B15").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-54
    Range("D15").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=60
    Range("B85:B88").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D85:D88").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("G88").Select

End Sub
```

Here is the code from module 2:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportPrices()

    Dim RawData As String
    Dim RawFile As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    RawData = Sheets("Prices").Range("O1")
    RawFile = Sheets("Prices").Range("O2")
        
   If Dir(RawData) <> "" Then
     
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=RawData
        Range("a:i").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Sheets("Prices").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Windows(RawFile).Close savechanges:=False
    Else
        MsgBox "Please make sure " & RawFile & " is in the Raw Data folder!"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Calculate
        End
    End If
    
    Calculate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

Here is the macro RefreshAllPMWS:

```
Public Sub RefreshAllPMWS()
Dim objRange As Range
Dim objSheet As Worksheet

For Each objSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, objSheet.Range("A1").Value2, "<?") Then
        RefreshNormalSheet objSheet.Name
    End If
Next

Application.Calculate
RefreshAllPivotCache
Application.Calculate
ImportPrices

End Sub
```

Here is the code for RefreshAllPivotCache

```
Public Sub RefreshAllPivotCache()
    Dim oCache As PivotCache
    Application.Calculate

    For Each oCache In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
        'do not refresh pricing profile if skipped
        oCache.Refresh
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know what line the error is occurring on? There are a few ways to find out where the error is occurring, but if you don't know that should be your starting point for debugging

Comment: You mention an error concerning "RefreshAllPMWS", but your code does not even mention "RefreshAllPMWS", so at least there are some holes in the information you provide.

Comment: Not related maybe to your posted problem, but your macros are full of implicit workbook/sheet references which might work OK when run from Excel but when run via automation are prone to break or produce wrong results.

Comment: Essentially RefreshPMWS is a macro I created which is the one actually called by the auto-run program.  This macro calls module 2, but doesn't call module 1, so I'm not understanding how that issue is even arising. According to the debugger, the error starts on the line with 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' @technoman23

Comment: @TimWilliams Unfortunately, I didn't actually write the code for module 1 or module 2.  I inherited the workbooks from a previous project and my limited knowledge on VBA makes it hard to troubleshoot.  The issue you bring up could certainly be a contributing factor

Comment: Would definitely help if you posted the macro which is actually being called...

Comment: @TimWilliams Provided the macro in the edit